# Using NCCL library from cupy in a cython file (.pyx)

Tags: cython, cupy

I am trying to import the function and definitions on https://github.com/cupy/cupy/blob/master/cupy_backends/cuda/libs/nccl.pyx
To a pyx file with a cimport, but it is not working.
I would like to know if it is even possible and if someone can give me some guidance about how to do it?
I noticed that on the cupy folder (after installing it with pip) the file nccl.pyx does not even exist just the .so for the library, thus the question if it is possible.

Thank you for the help!
This is my first question here so sorry if there is a mistake!

Comment: Replied on the CuPy gitter chat: https://gitter.im/cupy/community?at=6281a8c946495f47cfe1c237

Comment: You could try the `cimport_from_pyx` compiler option (https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#Cython.Compiler.Options.cimport_from_pyx)